# Populating unbound field from another bound custom field

Tags: acumatica

I have a requirement to have a field on SalesOrder screen and the same field should appear on Shipment screen also for respective SalesOrder. And the user should be able to update these field on both the screen.

I created a bound field on Sales Order screen which user can save it. Then I created an unbound field on Shipment screen to show the text from Sales Order. For that I have written a SOShipment_RowSelected event and later for user to update it to the database, I have written SOShipment_RowUpdated. However, when I try to edit the field, it fires RowSelected event and it overwrites the editing and bring back in the same original value.

I have tried with SOShipment_ShipmentNbr_FieldUpdated & SOShipment_ShipmentNbr_FieldUpdating event but its not firing everytime.

Here is the code for Cache extension-

```html
public class SOOrderExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
{
 #region UsrNotesText
 [PXDBString(255)]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Pick List Notes")]
 public virtual string UsrNotesText { get; set; }
 public abstract class usrNotesText : IBqlField { }
 #endregion
}
 
public class SOShipmentExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOShipment>
{
 #region UsrNotesText
 [PXString(255)]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Pick List Notes")]
 public virtual string UsrNotesText { get; set; }
 public abstract class usrNotesText : IBqlField { }
 #endregion
}
```

SOShipmentExtension code-

```html
public class SOShipmentEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
{
 PXSelect<SOOrder> soOrder;

 protected virtual void SOShipment_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
 {
  if (e.Row != null)
  {
   SOOrder order = PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,
    LeftJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>,
     And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderType>>>,
    LeftJoin<SOShipment, On<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>,
    Where<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>.Select(Base);

   if (order != null)
   {
    SOOrderExtension orderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtension>(order);

    SOShipment soShipment = Base.Document.Current;

    SOShipmentExtension ext = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExtension>(soShipment);
    ext.UsrNotesText = orderExt.UsrNotesText;
   }
  }
 }

 protected virtual void SOShipment_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
 {
  SOShipment oldRow = (SOShipment)e.OldRow;
  SOShipment newRow = (SOShipment)e.Row;

  if (oldRow != null || newRow != null)
  {
   SOShipmentExtension oldExt = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExtension>(oldRow);
   SOShipmentExtension newExt = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExtension>(newRow);


   if (oldExt.UsrNotesText != newExt.UsrNotesText)
   {
    {
     SOOrder order = PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,
     LeftJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>,
      And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderType>>>,
     LeftJoin<SOShipment, On<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>,
     Where<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>.Select(Base);

     soOrder.Current = order;

     if (order != null)
     {
      SOOrderExtension orderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtension>(order);

      orderExt.UsrNotesText = newExt.UsrNotesText;
      soOrder.Update(order);
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: RowSelected is not a good place for data updates. Should only be for UI stuff such as visible, enabled, etc. What about RowInserted?

Comment: RowInserted doesn't work either. I thought that will fire only when inserting new row for primary DAC. I know RowSelected is not a good place for setting some default value, however no other event works for me for some reason.

Comment: If all else fail, SOShipment_UsrNotesText_FieldSelecting shoud do it.

Comment: The issue is no such event is triggering. I am using Acumatica version 17.203.0029, will there be any issue with that event.

Comment: I've never had FieldSelecting not triggering. In fact it's often a last recourse solution to most eventing problems. Double check the syntax: public void SOShipment_UsrNotesText_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to initialize UsrNotesText elsewhere.

You can use PXDefault attribute:

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<SOOrderExtension.usrNotesText, Where< [...] >>))]
```

Or FieldDefaulting event handler:

```
public void SOShipment_UsrNotesText_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
   e.NewValue = [...]
}
```

Sometimes you also want to re-initialize when user changes key fields that are not re-triggering the default.:

```
public void SOShipment_ShipmentNbr_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    SOShipment shipment = e.Row as SOShipment;

    if (shipment != null)
    {
        SOShipmentExtension shipmentExt = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExtension>(shipment);

        if (shipmentExt != null)
        {
            shipmentExt.UsrNotesText = [...];
        }
    }
}
```

In such case manually re-triggering FieldDefaulting event with RaiseFieldDefaulting is often a better option.

However method you choose to initialize avoid setting the field value in RowSelected because that event is called at times when you don't want to initialize the custom field.

Comment: SOShipment_UsrNotesText_FieldDefaulting Event is not firing. Do I need to make some other changes to make it fire?

Comment: Do you have [PXDefault] attribute on the DAC Field?

Comment: The RaiseFieldDefaulting method of PXCache can also be used to trigger the event.

Comment: I do not have PXDefault attribute on DAC field. Also even if I want to use RaiseFieldDefaulting method to trigger, where should I write that code to trigger.

Comment: It depends how you want to approach this. The easy way is to add [PXDefault] attribute to the DAC field so the FieldDefaulting event is called by the framework. If for some reason you don't want to use the PXdefault event  framework then you could use RaiseFieldDefaulting in FieldSelecting event but that would be quite silly as it brings nothing useful over setting [PXDefault]. You could just as well initialize your value in FieldSelecting. For semantics reason I think FieldDefaulting is more appropriate.

Comment: So for that reason, should I have to include PXDefault attribute and FieldDefaulting event together? If yes, then what should I write PXDefault like just include attribute {PXDefault()]

Comment: Yes and yes. [PXDefault] DAC attribute on UsrNotesText field and this event handler in your graph: public void SOShipment_UsrNotesText_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)

Comment: In some cases you can put the BQL query in PXDefault and that's fine so you don't even need the event handler. For more complex dynamic logic, you can use PXDefault attribute without the query and perform the initialization in the FieldDefaulting handler. To have FieldDefaulting called by the system it needs PXDefault attribute but it's not necessary to give it a BQL query.

Comment: Finally FieldSelecting is at rescue. So SOShipment_UsrNotesText_FieldSelecting and SOShipment_RowUpdated event worked. Thanks @HB_ACUMATICA.